# How to make permutations satisfying conditions using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get permutations of a column from one sheet automatically updated in another sheet (of the same spreadsheet) - while satisfying some conditions.

Eg. This is a dummy table with dummy values for example to illustrate my problem/goal.

Sheet 1

`a   2   3`

`b   4   8`

`c   3   5`

`d   11  7`

`e   7   15`

I want to have combinations of column1 such that the sum of values of their column2 is say 20 +/- 5 and column3 is 15 +/- 3. In order to achieve this, the combinations can include multiples of one element too - like 1/2 a or 3 b.

So, for example, one set of combinations in Sheet 2 would be

```
column1 = a + d + 1/2 e
column2 = 16.5
column3 = 17.5
```

I've only ever done basic coding so far and I really have no idea how to go about this, any help would be much appreciated :(

Comment: You can start with [optimization service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/optimization/linear-optimization-service). But you'll only get 1 combination.

Comment: Thanks! But I need all possible combinations :-/ I was thinking of doing a very basic for loop and adding elements one by one and checking the conditions after each addition. But it's gonna be a very time-consuming one..